# WooCommerce | Add notification in shipping rate table based on the total weight of the cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, shipping-method

I am trying to add a **notification** to the **shipping totals** row on the WooCommerce shopping cart page as soon as two conditions are met.

1. Shipping method local_pickup is available

AND

2. the total weight of the products in my cart are above 14999 grams.

I've been playing around with the code uderneath, which already hides certain shipping methods (succesfully) but I'm unable to add a simple notification when the conditions are met.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_shipping_notification', 9999, 2 );
    
function woocommerce_shipping_notification( $rates, $package ) {
     
     if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() > 14999 ) {
       
         if ( isset( $rates['local_pickup:1'] ) )
             
             unset( $rates['flat_rate:2'], $rates['local_pickup:7'] );
            
            echo "My notification";
     }

    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) return;

add_action('wp', function() {

    if ( is_cart() && !WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        
        $cart = WC()->cart;
        $products = $cart->get_cart_contents();
        $cat_ids = array('20', '22');
        $product_categories = array();
        $product_categories_ids = array();
        foreach($cat_ids as $key => $cat_id) {
            $product_categories = array_merge(
                $product_categories,
                get_categories(array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'child_of' => $cat_id,  
                ))
            );
        }

        foreach($product_categories as $key => $category) {
            $product_categories_ids[] = $category->term_id;
        }

        $categories_included = function() use ( $products, $product_categories_ids ) {
            foreach( $products as $key => $product ) {              
                $terms = wp_get_object_terms(array($product['product_id']), 'product_cat');
                foreach( $terms as $_key => $term ) {       
                    if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $product_categories_ids) )
                        return true;
                }               
            }
            return false;
        };
        
        $only_pick_up = $categories_included() || $cart->get_cart_contents_weight() > 15000;    
        if ( $only_pick_up ) {

            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', function() {
                echo 
                    '<div>
                        <h3>Please contact us to discuss the delivery options</h3>
                    </div>';
            });                 

            add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', function() {
                foreach(WC()->shipping()->packages[0]['rates'] as $key => $rate) {
                    if ( $rate->__get('instance_id') != 18 ) {
                        unset(WC()->shipping()->packages[0]['rates'][$key]);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

});
```